# What is the equivalent code of SQL query in C# with linq to datatable?

Tags: c#, linq

This is my query in T-SQL and I want to do the exact thing in C# using linq to datatable.

```
select
    @found = MorningIsWorking, 
    @Sh_startTime = MorningStart, 
    @Sh_endTime = MorningEnd 
from t 
where 
    t.plannum = @pn and 
    t.Date = @datepart and 
    (@timepart between MorningStart and MorningEnd)
```

Which `MorningIsWorking` is boolean,`MorningStart`and `MorningEnd` and `@timepart` is time and `@datepart` is DateTime

Edited

This is what I did but I don't know is it right or not and how to get wanted values in variables.

```
var res = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                  where row.Field<string>("plannum") == "995" &
                  row.Field<DateTime>("date") == Convert.ToDateTime("2016-08-25 10:25:00").Date &
                  Convert.ToDateTime(timepart) >= row.Field<DateTime>("MorningStart") &
                  Convert.ToDateTime(timepart) < row.Field<DateTime>("MorningEnd")
                  select row;
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried already and what is not working?

Comment: @L-Four Question Edited.

Comment: Depending on the size of the data set, I believe executing the query in the database would be much more efficient than selecting the entire table then filtering in C#. Alternatively I would cast each row in the datatable to a typed object which will make filtering using linq much easier.

Comment: @Anth12 The datatable does not have more than 30 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this Code and it Worked for me.

```
DataRow row = dt.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault
            (r => (DateTime)r["date"] == timeToCompare.Date
            & r.Field<string>("plannum") == "0995" &
            tp >= r.Field<TimeSpan>("MorningStart") &
            tp < r.Field<TimeSpan>("MorningEnd"));
```

And then using this to get values :

```
sh_starttime = row["MorningStart"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is the LINQ for what you are trying to accomplish, based on what information you have provided.

```
DateTime timepart = new DateTime(2017,2,7);
DateTime datepart = new DateTime(2016, 8, 25, 10, 25, 0);
string plannum = "995";

using (DataSet1 dt = new DataSet1())
{
     var res = from row in dt.t.AsEnumerable()
          where row.plannum == plannum &&
          row.Date == datepart &&
          timepart >= row.MorningStart &&
          timepart < row.MorningEnd
          select row;

     foreach (var row in res)
     {
          var found = row.MorningIsWorking;
          var shStartTime = row.MorningStart;
          var shEndTime = row.MorningEnd;
     }
}
```

Alternatively, if you are expecting only a single row to be returned, you could leave out the foreach loop as follows.

```
DateTime timepart = new DateTime(2017,2,7);
DateTime datepart = new DateTime(2016, 8, 25, 10, 25, 0);
string plannum = "995";

using (DataSet1 dt = new DataSet1())
{
     var res = (from row in dt.t.AsEnumerable()
          where row.plannum == plannum &&
          row.Date == datepart &&
          timepart >= row.MorningStart &&
          timepart < row.MorningEnd
          select row).Single();


     var found = res.MorningIsWorking;
     var shStartTime = res.MorningStart;
     var shEndTime = res.MorningEnd;
}
```

Comment: What is MyData in dt.MyData.

Comment: This was just the name of a test table that I had set up.  You would change this to whatever the name of your table is.  In the SQL you posted above, your table name is "t", so you would replace "MyData" with "t".

Comment: I edited my code examples to show the table name of "t" for further clarity.

Comment: It raises Error when adding anything to dt after dot : Error 6 'System.Data.DataSet' does not contain a definition for 't' and no extension method 't' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataSet' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: DataSet1 is the name of your data set.  You did not include the name of your data set in the examples above, so I had created one with a default name.  You will need to change DataSet1 to whatever your data set is actually named.